# Need idea how to go about fingerprint access control system in C#

Tags: c#-4.0, sdk, access-control, biometrics

I am developing membership software with C#, but I need to implement access control and also searching for members with fingerprint technology. Any ideas how I could go about that?

Answer (score 1):

[SourceAFIS](http://sourceforge.net/projects/sourceafis/) works well and is C#. I know a Java shop that wrote their client code in C#  primarily so they could use it.

Comment: Thanks Very much. what database are the image stored to.

Comment: I don't think it implements any storage, only fingerprint matching and analysis algorithms.